# Radio Button Click Yes Show English and Click No Show Bangla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to translate my page using custom translator . When I select the button Bangla than whole Page translate into bangla and when I click in English than the whole page return into original language English.

Default its show English div content but when I click Bangla its show bangla div content only and hide English Div Content and When I also click English than The Bangla div content hide and Show only English div content.

Here is the Html Code :

```css
   .switch-field {
   font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
   padding: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   }

   .switch-title {
   margin-bottom: 6px;
   }

   .switch-field input {
   position: absolute !important;
   clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
   height: 1px;
   width: 1px;
   border: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   }

   .switch-field label {
   float: left;
   }

   .switch-field label {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 80px;
   background-color: #e4e4e4;
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-align: center;
   text-shadow: none;
   padding: 6px 14px;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:    all 0.1s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition:     all 0.1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition:      all 0.1s ease-in-out;
   transition:         all 0.1s ease-in-out;
   }

   .switch-field label:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   }

   .switch-field input:checked + label {
   background-color: #8dd400;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   }

   .switch-field label:first-of-type {
   border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
   }

   .switch-field label:last-of-type {
   border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
   }
```

```html
   <!--LANGUAGE SELECTOR-->

   <div align="left">
  
    <div class="switch-field">
      <div class="switch-title">Select Language :</div>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="switch_2" value="yes" checked/>
      <label for="switch_left">English</label>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="switch_2" value="no" />
      <label for="switch_right">বাংলা</label>
    </div>

   </div>

  <!--LANGUAGE Translate -->
</br>

  <div id="en_USA_lan">
  What would you like to list?
  </div>      

  <div id="bn_BD_lan">
  আপনি কি লিস্ট করতে চান ?
  </div>

 <!--LANGUAGE Translate -->


 <!--LANGUAGE SELECTOR-->
```

I am trying it using toggle but I cant get my desired result.

```
   <script>

    $(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#switch_left").click(function() {
            $("#switch_right_view").fadeToggle();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#switch_right").click(function() {
            $("#switch_right_view").fadeToggle();
        });
    });

</script>

<style>

    #switch_right_view {
            display: none;
            }
</style>
```

Thanks to All for help me about the api project .

Comment: Please show what you tried to do already.

Comment: I am using this one <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'bn', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script> but I want to do it using api and jquery manually thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your script to following, It should work fine. 
(Don't forget to add jQuery.)

**EDIT :** Working Snippet using classes instead of IDs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".bn_BD_lan").hide();

   $("#switch_right").click(function() {
      $(".en_USA_lan").hide();
      $(".bn_BD_lan").show();
   });
   $("#switch_left").click(function() {
      $(".en_USA_lan").show();
      $(".bn_BD_lan").hide();
   });    
});
```

```css
/* Do not worry Just minified your css to reduce space. */

.switch-field{font-family:"Lucida Grande",Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif;padding:0;overflow:hidden}.switch-title{margin-bottom:6px}.switch-field input{position:absolute!important;clip:rect(0,0,0,0);height:1px;width:1px;border:0;overflow:hidden}.switch-field label{float:left;display:inline-block;width:80px;background-color:#e4e4e4;color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);font-size:14px;font-weight:400;text-align:center;text-shadow:none;padding:6px 14px;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.1);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.1);-webkit-transition:all .1s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all .1s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:all .1s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .1s ease-in-out;transition:all .1s ease-in-out}.switch-field label:hover{cursor:pointer}.switch-field input:checked+label{background-color:#8dd400;color:#FFF;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none}.switch-field label:first-of-type{border-radius:4px 0 0 4px}.switch-field label:last-of-type{border-radius:0 4px 4px 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div align="left">
    <div class="switch-field">
        <div class="switch-title"> Select Language: </div>
        <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="switch_2" value="yes" checked />
        <label for="switch_left"> English </label>
        <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="switch_2" value="no" />
        <label for="switch_right"> বাংলা </label>
    </div>
</div>
</br>
<div class="en_USA_lan"> What would you like to list ? </div>
<div class="bn_BD_lan"> আপনি কি লিস্ ট করতে চান ? </div>

<div class="en_USA_lan"> I love you.</div>
<div class="bn_BD_lan"> আমি তোমায় ভালোবাসি.</div>
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: Add JQuery first.

Comment: Add this line in your head section. `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Its only work in one place but when I want to use this in one page more place its didn't work like : <!--ENGLISH--> 
<div id="en_USA_lan">
<fieldset class=""><label>What ?</label>
</div>      
<!--ENGLISH END-->
<!--BANGLA-->
<div id="bn_BD_lan">
<fieldset class=""><label> কি ? </label>
</div>
<!--BANGLA END-->
  
<!--ENGLISH--> 
<div id="en_USA_lan">
<fieldset class=""><label>What?</label>
</div>      
<!--ENGLISH END-->
<!--BANGLA-->
<div id="bn_BD_lan">
<fieldset class=""><label>আপনি ? </label>
</div>
<!--BANGLA END--> like 1st one is work but the 2nd one didn't thanks.

Comment: You can not give same ID to element more than once in document.

Comment: Better you need to switch to classes.

Comment: Checkout Edit i made. This time using classes.